# When is the sum of a weak-$*$ closed convex cone and a subspace also weak-$*$ closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convexity, convex-optimization

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Suppose $C \subset X^*$ is a convex cone and $V \subset X^*$ is a subspace, and suppose both $C$ and $V$ are closed in the weak-$*$ topology. Are there any general sufficient conditions available for showing that $C+V$ is weak-$*$ closed?

Edit: In the particular case I'm looking at, I know that $C \cap V = \{0\}$,
that $C-C = X^*$,
and that $C+V$ is norm closed. Does this help?

Comment: I guess you realize that if $C$ is a subspace then $C+V$ is weak$^*$ closed if and only if it is normed closed? That follows from the fact that if an adjoint operator has closed range, then it has weak$^*$ closed range. Perhaps if you unravel the proof of this fact, you will see that the same is true when $C$ is just a cone.

Comment: Is this really true? For instance, $c_0$ in $\ell^\infty$ is norm closed but not weak-$*$ closed. I believe that norm closedness and weak closedness are equivalent.

Comment: You are assuming that $C$ and $V$ are weak$^*$ closed.  My comment obviously was made for weak$^*$ closed $C$ and $V$.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I understand your comment now. So if the sum of two weak-$*$ closed subspaces is norm closed, then it is also weak-$*$ closed. I've been able to verify this, but at the moment I don't see how to make the proof work for a cone.